# Keeping Selenium browser active

Tags: java, selenium

I'm using `Selenium HtmlUnitDriver` and wondering is it possible somehow to keep the state of this driver.
I mean that to test something on the page I have to load the driver -> load and add cookies -> go through the login page -> get required page.
It takes too much time to do it everytime.
Is there something like a 'server state' or maybe I need to serialize and save-load the driver?
Thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't have to go through the login page if you're also setting cookies. Are you sure the cookies are working? Some browsers prevent you from setting cookies unless the browser window is already viewing a page on the same site, so you might have to navigate to e.g. the homepage (or a blank page on the same site) before setting cookies.

Comment: Yes, I know about that. Cookies are working and I don't have to log in every time. But still that navigation everytime takes time. It would be good to have a copy of this driver on a certain page. Of course if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I've managed to solve my question, I'll leave this here:
1. I took `selenium-server-standalone` and run it with `-browserSessionReuse -timeout 3600 -browserTimeout 600` to keep my session alive.
2. Made my class:

```
public class MyRemoteWebDriver extends RemoteWebDriver {
....
@Override
protected void startSession(Capabilities desiredCapabilities, Capabilities requiredCapabilities) {
    String sid = loadSessionID("SID_NAME");
    if (sid != null) {
        super.startSession(desiredCapabilities, requiredCapabilities);
        log.info("Old SID: " + sid);
        setSessionId(sid);
        try {
            getCurrentUrl();
            log.info("Old url: " + getCurrentUrl());
        } catch (WebDriverException e) {
            sid = null;
        }
    }
    if (sid == null) {
        super.startSession(desiredCapabilities, requiredCapabilities);
        saveSessionID(getSessionId().toString());
        log.info("New SID: " + getSessionId().toString());
    }
  }
}
```

So, this way I can store this SessionId in the db and re-use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a singleton webdriver instead of creating one for each test.
Something like that:

```
class SingletonWebdriver {
    private static Webdriver driver;
    public static Webdriver getDriver() {
        if(driver == null) {
            createDriver();
        }
        return driver;
    }
}
```

And then you may call getDriver to retrieve the same driver, but in many cases it's a good practice to make each test in a diferent session.

Comment: I'm using such kind of webdriver singleton in my app. Maybe I got you wrong but I have to stop the whole app to make changes and launch it again. This singleton will not help me in this case.